# Is there a fast way to classify RGB triplets into color groups?

Tags: colors, computer-vision, accessibility

I am developing a program that helps visually impaired people identify the colors of objects around them. For this task, there are two steps:

1. Find the dominant colors in an image in the form of RGB triplets, i.e. (200, 25, 40).
2. Categorize the RGB triplet into the correct color group in order to report it to the user, for example red.

I have implemented step 1 successfully. How can I do step 2? Keeping in mind the following considerations:

1. The method should be fast and easy to execute.
2. It should be able to distinguish between light colors of different hues (such as light blue and light pink) as well as dark colors of different hues (such as navy blue and maroon).
3. The user pictures will be taken under natural lighting.
4. Since the primary users of my application are visually impaired people, there is little tolerance to mistakes.
5. The color groups need not be super specific. The following groups suffice: red, green, blue, yellow, pink, orange, purple, beige, white, gray, black.

I have no experience working with colors in similar applications, so sorry in advance if the question is trivial.

Comment: Hm. Dou you can use HSV color space?

Comment: Hi Nuzhny, do you know how I can define the HSV thresholds that discriminate between different color groups?

Answer (score 1):

This can be posed as color segmentation using Gaussian Mixture Models. The basic idea is that a color image is the combination of multiple color's, each parametrized by a gaussian random variable. [This](https://medium.com/sanchit-gupta/color-segmentation-using-gmm-7a8d900e48b) is a helpful tutorial, and there are open source projects available online.

Comment: Hi, Sai. Thanks for your input. I have already been able to output the relevant RGB triplets. I am just having trouble naming them.